# Error about the ffmpeg on heroku We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ffmpeg, carrierwave

I am trying to upload a video on heroku use the 'carrierwave' and 'streamio-ffmpeg'.

I've movement without any problems at local,
As a result of deploying the same thing to heroku,
Uploaded point in time 
”We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information”
 and you get an error.

I think what should I install ffmpeg on Heroku but does not go well even try various.
And how do you will be able to upload videos on heroku if?

It should be noted that, although I see a question that is similar, "heroku run rake db: migrate" In my problem did not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command in your terminal `heroku logs`.You will find the errors in the logs.

Comment: Thanks.Error I think here's.  
ffmpeg is whether you do not know absolutely for me to say that there is no where in hell. Please help me.  

2015-01-06T12:55:09.240961+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 223ms  
2015-01-06T12:55:09.246956+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - ffmpeg):  
2015-01-06T12:55:09.246959+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/uploaders/video_uploader.rb:52:in `screenshot'  
2015-01-06T12:55:09.246961+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-01-06T12:55:09.246958+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/uploaders/video_uploader.rb:52:in `new'

Comment: Is your code is working in development environment?Have you installed the gem `rails_12factor`?If not then add this code in your gemfile `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`.

Comment: Reply Thank you.  
Yes,as a result of examined,  
In the local rails_12factor (0.0.3, 0.0.2) has been installed.  
In the Heroku rails_12factor (0.0.3, 0.0.2)　has been installed.  

In the Gemfile,
#group :production do
  gem "rails_12factor"
#end

Comment: I ffmpeg installed successfully on Heroku By using the "https://github.com/HYPERHYPER/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg", resolves all of the error, and succeeded in upload.

I would like to thank all of the people and Uday kumar das.